# Mongorestore behaviour

Tags: mongodb

I am upgrading mongodb from 2.6 to 4.0 version now. We are targeting no down time for our application(There are multiple app instances). So to achieve that we devised the following strategy

1. First install a version 4.0 of mongo in new machine
2. Take a dump of data from mongo 2.6 through *mongodump* command
3. Restore the data collected from mongo 2.6 to mongo 4.0 through 'mongorestore'
4. Change the app instance to query to new mongo server in round robin fashion
5. After all instances are started
6. Take a dump of mongo 2.6 server again
7. Restore the dump created in above step to mongo 4.0 server

To create mongo dump in mongo 2.6, i used the below command

`mongodump --db $dbname $folder`

To restore the dump created from the above step,

I used the below command

`mongorestore --db $dbname --collection $collectionName $bsonFileofCollection`.

The restoration of data in *step 3* works fine.

But while the *mongorestore* is run during *step 7*, i am getting below errors for existing documents in the collections.

*- E11000 duplicate key error index: db.collection.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5cacc02e3d6f6356c843e36b') }*

I understand from the above error the index already exists for this _id. But as i read from mongo docs about mongorestore, it only does insert, So the the documents which have same *_id* should get ignored.

Please help me to understand why i am getting this error and how to resolve the error

Answer (score 0):

If you can use MongoDB Atlas the Live Migrate feature will automate this process for you.

https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/cloud/migrate-from-aws-to-atlas/

You restore will always fail as the second restore includes original docs.

You could write a small program to manually cut over the residue docs starting from the last write after the first dump.

Comment: I understand we have sophisticated feature but i want to understand the behavior of *mongorestore*  as it doesn't match with mongodocs.

As per documentation

*That is, if restoring documents to an existing database and collection and existing documents have the same value _id field as the to-be-restored documents, mongorestore will not overwrite those documents.*

If overwrite doesn't happen, then there shouldn't be case for index too..